# Wind Chill Calculator and math formulas in definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, definition

This should be the last error I am getting

```
velocity = wind_speed * 0.16
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

any ideas? pretty sure i need to define an input as a float, Sorry I am still new to python.

```
def calc_wind_chill(f_temp, wind_speed):
    """ float, float -> float
    returns wind_chill_temperature (F)
    given farenheit temperature and
    wind_speed in miles per hour
    """
    velocity = wind_speed * 0.16
    chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * f_temp)-(35.75 * velocity) +(0.4275 * f_temp * velocity)

    return chill
#end def



while True:
    question=input("w for windchill or q for quit: " )
    if question=="w":
        temperature=input("Air tempature in Fahrenheit: ")
        wind=input("What is the windspeed in mph: ")
        calc_wind_chill(temperature, wind)
        print("Wind Chill", chill, " F", temperature, "F ", "wind speed:", wind)
        wind_chill_2= calc_wind_chill(temperature, wind +10)
        print("wind Chill:", wind_chill_2, " F", temperature, "F  ", "wind speed:", wind + 10)

    elif question=="q":
        print("have a nice day!")
        break
```

Comment: Check the indentation of that `return` statement.

Comment: Also, those `float("...")` in the `input` calls, those make no sense.

Comment: you're right about the return statement but it still gives the same error

Comment: Space versus tabs anywhere? Oh, and the comment block, shouldn't that be indented too?

Comment: input() returns a string, so you need to convert it to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside of a function, including comments, needs indented...

```
def calc_wind_chill(f_temp, wind_speed):
    """ float, float -> float
    returns wind_chill_temperature (F)
    given farenheit temperature and
    wind_speed in miles per hour
    """
    velocity = wind_speed ** 0.16
    chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * f_temp)-(35.75 * velocity) +(0.4275 * f_temp * velocity)

    return chill
```

Comment: *head slap* that's what I get for copy pasting from my old work

Comment: @JeremyBradley happens to everyone.

Comment: @JeremyBradley as Catalin said in the comments, you should have `temperature = float(input(...))` b/c input returns a string, so you need to convert it to some sort of number to perform mathematical caclculations.